# Unity - Use SQLite database in other folder than StreamingAssets

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

I made a cross matching words Unity game for Android devices. Currently I am using an SQLite Database in StreamingAssets folder for the words in the game and everything works great.

The problem is that my database in StreamingAssets folder is easily accessible to anyone.

Is there any way to move and access my database from other folder except StreamingAssets?

I am using the code below to access my database on Android:

```
string databaseName = "/MyDatabase.db";
StartCoroutine(SetDatabase(databaseName));
return Path.Combine("URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + databaseName);
 
private IEnumerator SetDatabase(string databaseName)
{
   string path = Path.Combine("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets" + databaseName);
   UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(path);
   yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();            
 
   if (unityWebRequest.isNetworkError || unityWebRequest.isHttpError)
         AppHelper.Dbg("SetDatabase()", this + ": " +unityWebRequest.error);
 
   /// Retrieve results as binary data.
   byte[] data = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
 
   /// Writes the DB in the persistent memory.
   File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + databaseName), data);
}
```

Attached a screenshot of my .apk file showing my database in StreamingAssets folder.

[image]

Comment: So first up, why?  'Security by obscurity' is not really security, especially on Android.  Secondly, if it's even possible, you will absolutely need an express 'access filesystem' permission from the user to write somehting outside of persistenDataPath.

Comment: Instead of 'hiding' the file, why not just encode it? I assume it's in clear text, so what if you swizzle the values to a different encode type (binary? UTF8? Something else?).  That said, doesn't SQLite support full-file encryption?

Comment: `The problem is that my database in StreamingAssets folder is easily accessible to anyone.` Afaik that is true for the `persistentDataPath` but not for `StreamingAssets`. The streaming assets are packed into the APK and not directly accessible anymore .. that's the whole reason why you have to use a `UnityWebRequest` and can't just `File.Open` it on Android. ..

Comment: Also please remove this `while (!unityWebRequest.isDone) { }` .. you are already waiting for exactly this by using `yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();` so it is completely redundant

Comment: @Immersive My first try was to encrypt my database and I was looking for file encryption on SQLite but couldn't find one.

Comment: @derHugo I updated my question with a screenshot when I open my .apk file showing my database in StreamingAssets folder. Thanks for the !unityWebRequest.isDone tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to the problem I had. I add my database in Resources folder and then use the code below to copy it in persistent memory and therefore the database is not visible in the .apk file.

```
private void CopyDefinitionsDatabaseFromResources()
{
    string RESOURCES_DATABASE_NAME = "words.bytes";
    string DATABASE_NAME = "words.db";
    
    TextAsset db = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(RESOURCES_DATABASE_NAME));
    byte[] data = db.bytes;
            
    // copy the database file from resources to persistent app path
    string destination = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, DATABASE_NAME);
    // writing file
    File.WriteAllBytes(destination, data); 
}
```